# Is it possible to forward messages to a Microsoft 365 mailbox with the same e-mail address?

Tags: email, outlook-web-app, microsoft-365

My organization has adopted Microsoft 365 for cloud services except e-mail, which is still managed on-premise. As my M365 account coincides with my e-mail address, now the same address refers to two different e-mail recipients: if a colleague sends an email message within a M365 service (e.g. Outlook) to my address, it is collected in my M365 mailbox; on the other hand, if the colleague sends an email message from outside M365 (e.g. from gmail) it arrives to my on-premise email client.

As this is very annoying, and since I am using all M365 services, I'd like to know if there is any possibility that a message from anywhere in the world arrives into my M365 mailbox. I don't have admin privileges on both M365 and on-premise email service. It would be great if my M365 mailbox could be reached from the outside so that I can forward all my messages arrived on-premise to my M365 mailbox.

Comment: Someone sure messed things up for you. If your company isn't using Exchange Online in Microsoft 365 then how are they able to send you an email from Microsoft 365? They would need to have, and be using, an Office 365 mailbox in order to send you an email from Microsoft 365. Where does your MX record point to? Is there an Exchange Hybrid in place? Do the Microsoft 365 users have Exchange Online licenses and do they have mailboxes in Exchange Online?

Comment: You should talk with the managers within your organization that configures things. They have messed up the configuration.